# Python Pandas: Why is numpy so much faster than Pandas for column assignment? Can I optimize further?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing

I am preprocessing data for a Machine Learning classification task by converting categorical variables to a binary matrix, primarily using `pd.get_dummies()`. This is applied to a single Pandas DataFrame column and outputs a new DataFrame with the same number of rows as the original and width of unique number of categorical variables in the original column.

I need to complete this for a DataFrame of shape: `(3,000,000 x 16)` which outputs a binary matrix of shape: `(3,000,000 x 600)`.

During the process, the step of converting to a binary matrix `pd.get_dummies()` is very quick, but the assignment to the output matrix was much slower using `pd.DataFrame.loc[]`. Since I have switch to saving straight to a `np.ndarray` which is **much** faster, I just wonder why? (*Please see terminal output at bottom of question for time comparison*)

**n.b.** As pointed out in comments, I could just all `pd.get_dummies()` on entire frame. However, some of the columns require tailored preprocessing, i.e: putting into buckets. The most difficult column to handle is a column containing a string of tags (seperated by `,` or `,`, which must be processed like this: `df[col].str.replace(' ','').str.get_dummies(sep=',')`. Also, the preprocessed training set and test set need the same set of columns (inherited from all_cols) as they might not have the same features present once they are broken into a matrix.

**Please see code below for each version**

DataFrame version:

```
def preprocess_df(df):
    with open(PICKLE_PATH + 'cols.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
        cols = pickle.load(handle)

    x = np.zeros(shape=(len(df),len(cols)))
    # x = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_cols)

    for col in df.columns:
        # 1. make binary matrix
        df_col = pd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=str(col))

        print "Processed: ", col,  datetime.datetime.now()

        # 2. assign each value in binary matrix to col in output
        for dummy_col in df_col.columns:
            x.loc[:, dummy_col] = df_col[dummy_col]

        print "Assigned: ", col,  datetime.datetime.now()

    return x.values
```

np version:

```
def preprocess_np(df):
    with open(PICKLE_PATH + 'cols.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
        cols = pickle.load(handle)

    x = np.zeros(shape=(len(df),len(cols)))

    for col in df.columns:
        # 1. make binary matrix
        df_col = pd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=str(col))

        print "Processed: ", col,  datetime.datetime.now()

        # 2. assign each value in binary matrix to col in output
        for dummy_col in df_col.columns:
            idx = [i for i,j in enumerate(all_cols) if j == dummy_col][0]
            x[:, idx] = df_col[dummy_col].values.T

        print "Assigned: ", col,  datetime.datetime.now()

    return x
```

**Timed outputs (`10,000` examples)**

DataFrame version:

```
Processed:  Weekday 
Assigned:  Weekday 0.437081  
Processed:  Hour 0.002366
Assigned:  Hour 1.33815
```

np version:

```
Processed:  Weekday   
Assigned:  Weekday 0.006992
Processed:  Hour 0.002632
Assigned:  Hour 0.008989
```

Is there a different approach to further optimize this? I am interested as at the moment I am discarding a potentially useful feature as it is too slow to process an extra `15,000` columns to the output.

Any general advice on the approach I am taking is also appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Can't you use get_dummies on the entire data.frame? Why are you applying it per column?

Comment: Ah! Interesting question, some of the columns require tailored preprocessing, i.e: putting into buckets. Moreover, one particular column handles lists of tags, which must be processed like this: `df[col].str.replace(' ','').str.get_dummies(sep=',')`. Also, the preprocessed training set and test set need the same set of columns (inherited from `all_cols`) as they might not have the same features present once they are broken into a matrix.

Comment: @jfive Generally it's best to output these as timedeltas, right? So it's more obvious what's going on. Just try subtracting the later dates from the earlier ones, or using `from timeit import default_timer as timer` and using that timer.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the feedback, I will switch these to delta now.

Comment: try to replace `x.loc[:, dummy_col] = df_col[dummy_col]` with `x[dummy_col] = df_col[dummy_col]`

Comment: @MaxU - I have tried that, it's certainly no faster than np. Admittedly, I haven't timed a diff, but I think it is slower than `.loc`

Comment: `pd.Categorical` might be worth investigating. It encodes the level information in the data type. Once you have preprocessed the data to make them categorical, you could call pd.get_dummies on the whole df.

Comment: @Zelazny7, Looks interesting, not sure if I can use that to handle the String lists of tags such as `tag1,tag2,tag3` being contained in a single cell of the DataFrame though

Comment: For the list of tags piece, `CountVectorizer` is your friend! `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer` Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/Zelazny7/c11c35aff39e775a84bdfe4ee0ad41ba

Comment: Thanks for creating the gist, I tried that that to get the following:

Input:

      `User Tags
    0       a,b
    1       b,c
    2         d
    3       e,f
    4      null`

Output:

    `matrix([[1],
            [1],
            [0],
            [1],
            [0]])`

Ideally the output matrix would have output shape (5,7), representing the 5 original rows and 7 unique tags

(This is the series `s = pd.Series(['a,b', 'b,c', 'd', 'e,f', 'null'])`)

Answer (score 1):

One experiment would be to change over to `x.loc[:, dummy_col] = df_col[dummy_col].values`. If the input is a series, pandas is checking the order of the indices for each assignment. Assigning with an ndarray would turn that off if it's unnecessary, and that should improve performance.